# implementing Excel if-like function with AWK

Tags: excel, linux, if-statement, awk

I have a question about Excel-if-function implementation with AWK. I have a csv file having eight columns
like below:

```
3,3,1,2,2,4,1,3
3,4,2,4,2,5,4,1
3,2,1,1,6,5,4,3
```

Each field can take only integer values from 1 to 6. I would like to give one point if the first column
is 1. In other cases, the score would be zero. In this MWE case, the point for all three row is zero because everyone answered as 3, not 1. If I wish to do this with MS Excel, I usually insert
one column righthand side and write a function like `=IF(A1=1,1,0)`. And then, by repeating
this procedures for all the eight columns, I can calculate the total score by summing up all the
inserted columns. In Excel language, this corresponds to `sum(I1:P1)`. If I assume that the correct answer is 1, for example, for all eight columns, the **expected transposed output** is `(2,1,2)`. I should also learn how to sum up the last eight columns in a row. I wonder how I can implement this type of function with `awk`. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: something like this: BEGIN { result = 0 } { if ($1 == 1) result++; } END { print result }

Comment: `awk -F, '$1 == 1' file | wc -l`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there was no expected output, I'm gonna go with my mental image of what it would look like in Excel (thank god haven't used that in ages):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","            # need separators as there are no boxes to fill
}
{
    nf=NF                 # securing NF for future abuse
    for(i=1;i<=nf;i++)    # automatically repeating the procedure
        $(nf+1)+=($i==1)  # the procedure
    s+=$NF                # total sum
    print                 # output
}
END {
    print s               # output the total sum after records
}' file
```

Output:

```
3,3,1,2,2,4,1,3,2
3,4,2,4,2,5,4,1,1
3,2,1,1,6,5,4,3,2
5
```